# access android external SD card from native code

Tags: android, android-ndk-r5

I'm developing a native apk for android with NDK 5.

My question is, how do I access to write and read from external SD card from native code?

Comment: could you be more specific? Do you have a question about which path to read from or how to open a file in C?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works the same as Java code.

You need to use the SDK API [Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#getExternalStorageDirectory%28%29) in your Java code and then pass that to your native code, accessing it like a normal path.

Comment: You're welcome. Please remember to mark answers if they are correct.

Comment: if any configuration need to do for native service? I just wrote a native service with C, and try to access file/directory in sdcard. however, it often return errno 2.